# Unix command to write particular pattern

Tags: shell, unix

I have a log file in unix which has information of all fatal logs generated from all user.

I am trying to read the key information from this file.

The key is (User id) where the fatal has occured and (Message)the reason for the fatal

I want to read the file line by line and grep for a pattern in that line and if it exists in that line, write the same to a new file.

I tried with the following code

```
for file in `cat fatalLogInfo.txt`
do
        grep -i "User Id========*" $file >>abcd1.txt
        grep -i "Message"        $file >>abcd1.txt
done
```

Please correct me.

Comment: Can you show a sample of `fatalLogInfo.txt`? Also, what doesn't work, and what is your expected output? You don't say what's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I susepct you can do that all in one go, like this:

```
egrep -hi "User ID=====|Message" $(cat fatalLogInfo.txt) > abcd1.txt
```

I use `egrep` so you can use the pipe symbol (`|`) to search for either of two things - namely `User Id===` or `Message`. I add `-h` to stop `grep` printing filenames, as it will do when you pass it more than one file to search in. Then I use `$()` to mean "the output of running the command inside the braces". As the command inside the braces prints a list of the filenames, the `$()` simply passes a list of filenames to the `grep` command for it to search in.

The advantage of this approach is that you do not have to execute a whole new process for `grep` for each file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the while loop:

```
while read -r line
do
    #do whatever want with the line
    part=$(grep -oP 'regex' <<<"$line") # and such
done < fatalLogInfo.txt
```

without to know the exact structure isn't possible to give better answer.